# pyaudio recording on Ubuntu using USB camera

Tags: python, audio

I can't seem to get recording work with pyaudio on Xubuntu 14.10.

After installing pyaudio, I follow the code example here: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples

```
"""PyAudio example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

all I got in return is the following message:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
* recording
* done recording
```

And an empty file. What have I done wrong?
I don't own a normal mic so I'm using the mic on a USB webcam, which works fine with things like audacity. Perhaps I need to tell pyaudio or whoever about this arrangement?

Comment: It looks like you did not compile the dependencies properly. Try installing with `sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not compile the dependencies properly. Try installing with the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

Comment: How do I recompile the dependencies once I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the unknown PCM card messages, I just edited /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf and commented out the lines beginning with pcm.rear, pcm.center_lfe and pcm.side. That stopped the following messages from showing up:
`ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear`
`ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe`
`ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side`